# SugarCRM Community Edition

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I've been facing a problem with the sugarCRM community edition. I downloaded the FastStack Windows edition and installed all its features. When I run the local host, it asks for a login. I've tried my account login and other log in names (admin admin, root root..), and changed my password several times but I always get a message to enter a valid username and password. I can log in to the sugarcrm.com account but I can't use the information on the local host. When I click the forgot your password button and enter the information, also a message displays "You must specify a valid User Name and Email Address."

Comment: This sounds like a case for the SugarCRM support forums rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: did you follow each step of the tuto? http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/sugarcrm/sugarcrm-installation.htm (on which step are you stuck?)

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember putting in an admin password during the installation? That would be the one you should be using.

See the installation guide for FastStack for more details at http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.2/-docs-User_Guides-Sugar_FastStack_Installation_Guide_CommunityEdition_6.2.0-Windows_FastStack.html.